# How to monitor NTP error message

Tags: ntp

I want to monitor NTP error message to catch synchronization fail like network unreachable, server error etc..

When I add logconfig =allall in /etc/ntp.conf, and restart ntpd, trying to get more information when error occurs, but the output information is not enough for me to monitor.

But, if I run ntp in debug mode, like "ntpd -u ntp:ntp -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g -D 4", I can get more detail information.

Could I just modify ntp config file to do the same thing as debug mode?

By the way, logconfig seems not written on man page.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which OS you are running this on, or trying to configure this for but... if its a linux OS then have a look in the following file.

`/etc/sysconfig/ntpd` that is the default options file which is read when the daemon is started. My default config contains `OPTIONS="-u ntp:ntp -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g"`

You should be able to modify that to suite your requirement of additional logging.